# Is it possible to inject YAML file to a service in Symfony?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony

I would like to inject a YAML configuration to a service in Symfony. Currently, I inject path of my bundle and a relative path to the file and parse it manually with `Yaml::parse` but is there an easier way to do this?
So the goal would be that the constructor of the service would receive an array of the already parsed YAML config.

---

To put some more detail about it:

Currently, I have a YAML file in a `Resources` directory in my bundle and to parse it in a service, I use something like this:

```
$yamlFile = sprintf(
        '%s/%s',
        $container->get('kernel')->getBundle('MyBundle')->getPath(),
        $pathToFile
);
```

So I have to inject both the container (can I somehow inject just the path to the bundle?) and the path to the file. I wouldn't mind restructuring my system a bit, e.g. put the yaml file in the config directory of the bundle, if that would help, but I'd like to keep it separate from other configuration.

Comment: As an alternative, I can think of creating a special service, that I could inject with the parameters and let it take care of the parsing, afterwards getting the parsed data out from it. But this seems like a task that might have already been solved in Symfony.

Comment: I don't see the exact requirements on configuration files but if you don't mind using the same format as conventional config files located in app/config, isn't the addition of extra resources to the app/config enough, even when you want to call it from services?

imports:
    - { resource: '%kernel.root_dir%/parameters.yml' }

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/configuration_organization.html

Comment: @ScalatronMotoroller I understand I could create another config file and import it like that, but since it's only related to one part of one bundle, coupling it like this with the root of the project seems not right. Btw, the example you've posted comes from a part where they show that it does _not_ work dynamically like that.

Comment: Yes, I agree that @Dmitry Grachikov's post is the best solution I know.

Comment: You could create a factory service that would take care of parsing the yaml thus removing the YAML dependency from your service class.  May or may not be worth the extra effort.  I also often add a my_bundle_dir parameter (in the dependency injection configuration class) so my code at least knows where the resources live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load needed configuration in bundle extension like described there: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html and save it to new parameter, or inject to any service you like.

Comment: Seems like the best solution... Except that I struggle for hours already with a "_There is no extension able to load the configuration for ..._" error. I've followed all the references for this I could find and I still cannot get the extension to work.

Comment: If anyone has a hint, I'd be thankful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361084/