# There is no extension able to load the configuration for "my_namespace"

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony

Similar question has been here a few times already but unfortunately I wasn't able to find the help needed in there.

I am trying to create a custom extension class in Symfony (3.1). I am following the cookbook [[1](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html),[2](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html)] but no matter what I try, I get the error

> InvalidArgumentException in YamlFileLoader.php line 404: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "czechnology_tools" (in [path_to_project]\src\Czechnology\ToolsBundle\DependencyInjection/../Resources/config\holidays.yml). Looked for namespace "czechnology_tools", found none

class`CzechnologyToolsExtension`:

```
<?php

namespace Czechnology\ToolsBundle\DependencyInjection;

// use ...

class CzechnologyToolsExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('holidays.yml');
    }
}
```

and the corresponding `Configuration.php` in the same directory:

```
<?php

namespace Czechnology\ToolsBundle\DependencyInjection;

// use ...

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('czechnology_tools');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('calendar')->defaultValue('default')->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

In the YAML file, I currently just have dummy content, trying to get it to work at all. `holidays.yml`:

```
czechnology_tools:
    calendar: foo
```

If I try to debug in console, I get this:

```
$ bin/console config:dump-reference czechnology_tools
# Default configuration for extension with alias: "czechnology_tools"
czechnology_tools:
    calendar:             default
```

So it seems to be that the extension is set correctly, with the correct alias. However, I still cannot get over the exception. Any hints?

Comment: is your bundle enabled in AppKernel. ? ...

Comment: @Drmjo Yes, the bundle is registered in Kernel and all the services in it work fine.

Comment: You can try to find out the config name. I have run into this many times, and most of the time symfony expects a different name.  Try setting the config `czechnology_tools `  in app/config.yml. Comment the line thats loading `holidays.yml` temporarily. Now you will get error something like `Looked for namespace "czechnology_tools", found <list of registered namespaces>`. Look for your config name in the registered namespaces.

Comment: @Broncha When I move the config to `app/config.yml` then it works. (I think the name of the namespace is correct. Actually I think using the console command mentioned above without the parameter is an easier way to show the namespaces: `$ bin/console config:dump-reference`.)

Comment: btw, I think the issue here is that the yaml/xml loaders inside Extensions are for loading services/routings generally. May be `czechnology_tools ` configuration has not yet been loaded. The error says it `Looked for namespace "czechnology_tools", found none` none of the configuration has been loaded yet!

Comment: @Broncha That's an interesting point. However, it seems to me that a number of guides I've found done it exactly the same as I did and it worked for them. Maybe somthing in newer Symfony versions changed that I haven't noticed.

Comment: Actually, I've also tried doing the same thing in a fresh Symfony installation (to be sure there are no sideeffects of my app) but I keep getting the same error there too. Maybe the extensions really aren't meant to allow config directly in the bundle but only in the app config. I'm not really any smarter from the symfony docs on this.

Comment: Another thought, may be your bundle is initialized wayy high in AppKernel.php

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that somewhere is your bundle architecture, there is a typo (maybe intentional, a bundle class named differently than the extension, ...).

First, run `bin/console debug:config`, in order to see if your bundle appears with a different alias of the one you're trying to use, you should have an output containing a line that looks like:

> CzechnologyToolsBundle | [the good alias]

If it doesn't appear at all, add the following to your bundle class:

```
namespace Czechnology\ToolsBundle;

use Czechnology\ToolsBundle\DependencyInjection\CzechnologyToolsExtension;

class CzechnologyToolsBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getContainerExtension()
    {
        return new CzechnologyToolsExtension();
    }
}
```

Plus, add the following method to your bundle extension:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getAlias()
{
    return 'czechnology_tools';
}
```

Hope it solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. The console command has the same output as the one I've posted in the comments above and yes, the alias of my bundle is there. I've also tried the `getAlias()` method before, to no help. I've also tried adding the `getContainerExtension()` method there but still keep getting the same error.